# How can I run a bat file from a remote browser

Tags: javascript, php, batch-file, browser, activex

I know this sounds like I want to use this for a virus or spyware but what I would like to do is run a bat file that will open a register on a POS system.  I have a PHP Point of Sale app that I wrote and I am hosting it on my server.

Clients run it from their browser.  I was thinking ActiveX might allow it even if it prompt the users to run the ActiveX.  I am not familiar with ActiveX but I have seen how viruses and spyware run.

I don't think Javascript will do it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so... if you want to start a batch file running on your system, you can download netcat, and say `nc -Lp1212 -e yourbatch.bat`

the -L means listen, and on windows means listen repeatedly, but you might wanna use -l on Linux. the p1212 means listen on port 1212, the post i often use. the -e means execute apon connection, and the yourbatch.bat is the file to execute.

Comment: I checked out Netcat website and I think this might work. I will have to test it out. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @DanielR, it means that anyone who connects to his machine on port 1212 will start the bat running, and will get all output from it. i believe this is what he wanted.... not sure `;/`

Comment: No, that's not what he wants. He wants to run the batch script on the client, not the server.

Comment: Nephi12 that is a good point about anybody that hits that port will trigger the bat file.  I will have to have some kind of authentication.  I know I can run remote commands using ssh from linux to linux.  Does anyone know if I can use ssh from linux to Windows and run the batch file that way?